# ng build throwing [error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: angular12

I have this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

```
styles.2f06433e92600f91a077.css - Error: styles.2f06433e92600f91a077.css from Css Minimizer
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

I'm using Angular 12 version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This means that the object on which you are calling the method .toLowerCase is of type undefined. This can either be by design and you can just add a check before calling it:

```js
if (str) str.toLowerCase()
```

Or if you didn't expect to have an undefined variable in that part of the code there is a mistake somewhere else, in that case I can't really help you.

Comment: I'm getting errors from this module 'postcss-merge-longhand' . Shall I remove this module

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the issue, you can maybe write a bug report for the package. Honestly I would just remove it if it's causing yo problems, it is what I would do but it may not apply to you. It seem that it's not the only error of this type they have: https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano/issues/1031